# Why can't I cast from Action to DispatchedHandler?

Tags: c#, uwp

G'day Folks,

I feel like I'm can't see something basic.

[Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Action);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) is defined as public delegate void Action().

[DispatchedHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.dispatchedhandler?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%2CVersion%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) is defined as public delegate void DispatchedHandler().

Yet the following code generates at the RunASync line: Error CS1503    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Action' to 'Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler'.

```
public static async Task DispatchToUI(Action action, CoreDispatcherPriority priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal )
{
    if (CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
    {
        action();
    }
    else
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync( priority, action );
    }
}
```

Adding an explicit conversion thus:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync( priority, (DispatchedHandler)action );
```

fails with Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'System.Action' to 'Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler'.

So one version of public delegate void() can't convert to a different version of public delegate void()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a delegate like that, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465113/casting-delegate) SO question.

You can, however, create a new delegate from the existing one:

```
public static async Task DispatchToUI(Action action, CoreDispatcherPriority priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal)
{
    if (CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
    {
        action();
    }
    else
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(priority, new DispatchedHandler(action));
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you could also use a lambda function that would implicitly convert it for you:

```
    public static async Task DispatchToUI(Action action, CoreDispatcherPriority priority = CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal )
    {
        if (CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync( priority, () => action() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something basic!