# .netcore PUT method 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have a simple model as that has 2 fields and with the following put method, i'm tring to update it in the db. Everymethod including delete works, however put method always returns a 405 error in Postman. (tried WebDAV solutions as well.) What am I missing here?

[image]

PUT METHOD:

```
{
    "MasterId":1,
    "MasterName":"Test"
}
```

Action

```
[HttpPut("{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutMaster(int id, Master master)
{
    if (id != master.MasterId)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    //...some code
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: First observation is that the called URL does not match the route template of the controller action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `[HttpPut("{id:int}")]` route attribute, you will need to refer your api with: http://localhost:5000/api/masters/{id}

In your exmample:

PUT http://localhost:5000/api/masters/1

So the `id` in the param also not needed:

```
[HttpPut("{id:int}")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> PutMaster(Master master)
```

And it is a bad practice to expose entity framework object to the client, you should use a DTO class and map it to the entity framework object.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to use EF model there?

Comment: DTO is good practice to minimize traffic, controlling serialization, security, separation of concerns  etc... see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5910546/6844481

Answer (score 13):

If you are using IIS to run your application and have WebDav module, that can be an issue. For some strange reason WebDav does not allow PUT.

I just uninstalled it, and it helped.

Comment: If you don't want to uninstall WebDav, you can also exclude the module by adding a web.config to the folder of the application. Add the following section to it:

`
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
`

Comment: Thank you! I would have never figured this out on my own!

Answer (score 10):

If your application is being hosted under IIS, running API in ASP.NET Core, include this line in the Web.Config file

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
             <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I had the same problem after publishing on host(plesk). with this solution my issue fixed.

Comment: For IIS, it is the correct solution

Comment: You'll probably have to remove the handler as well. I got 500 errors with only the module removed: `<handlers> <remove name="WebDAV" /> </handlers>`

Answer (score 2):

First observation is that the called URL

```
api/masters
```

does not match the route template of the controller action `[HttpPut("{id:int}")]` which would map to a URL like

```
api/masters/{id:int}
```

Call the correct URL that matches the action's route template

```
PUT api/masters/1
```

The error itself is because most likely you have another route that matches the provided URL but not the HTTP Verb. like a root `[HttpGet]` on one of the controller actions. This explains why you get a *405 Method Not Allowed* error and not a *404 Not Found* error

Answer (score 1):

Your method should be

```
 [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutMaster(int id,[FromBody]  Master master)
{}
```

You need to add `[FromBody]` attribute in the method.

Request url should be

```
PUT api/masters/1
```