# Cannot call API DELETE in ASP.NET core when running my tests (405 Method Not Allowed) . BUT it works in swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-delete, http-verbs

Maybe there are some sort of permissions I need to set up in the test webhost ? The Get and Post for the tests work fine. But get a HTTP 405 error when it tries to call the DELETE method on the controller.

```
    [HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<RfAttachmentModel>> DeleteByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        await _rfAttachmentService.DeleteByIdAsync(id);
        return NoContent();
    }


  public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("LocalTesting");

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase();

            ServiceProvider provider = services
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            services.AddDbContext<PwdrsContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Pwdrs");
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(provider);
            });

            ServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (IServiceScope scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                IServiceProvider scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                PwdrsContext db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<PwdrsContext>();
                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

                ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>> logger = scopedServices
                    .GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                try
                {
                    PwdrsContextSeed.SeedAsync(db, loggerFactory).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred seeding the " +
                        "database with test messages. Error: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT1 : Here is the method in the test project that makes the call

```
 [Fact]
    public async Task Delete_Item_By_Id()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseDelete = await Client.GetAsync("/api/RfAttachment/DeleteById/1");
        responseDelete.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        HttpResponseMessage responseGetAll = await Client.GetAsync("/api/RfAttachment/GetAll");
        responseGetAll.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string stringResponse = await responseGetAll.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<RfAttachment> result = JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RfAttachment>>(stringResponse)
            .ToList();

        Assert.Single(result);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the parameter in the httpdelete? maybe you are calling it in a badly way. Just  [HttpDelete] and check what happens

Comment: then the error is NOT FOUND since it is looking for a parameter.. I noticed UPDATE commands are giving the 405 too.. yet the GET and the POST are working fine :\

Comment: How is the url path you are calling? find the api endpoints in swagger and check how they should be called. please check if you are calling it exactly the same way as you have it in swagger

Comment: How do you host your app against which you run your tests? There're some hints: you might run against old version of the app in which httDelete had not been implemented. If you host in IIS or IISExpress, check web config it defines which methods are allowed.

Comment: 405 is Method Not Allowed.... We need to see the code you are using to call the api and the api controllers' declaration

Comment: I am using the IWebHostBuilder so my best guess is maybe there is some security issue not present in IIS Express

Comment: Show us the route attribute on controller. Also, did you check the network tab of your browser to see what is the url swagger constructs and calls?

Comment: [HttpDelete("{id:int}")]….. I changed it to [HttpGet("{id:int}")] and it works fine... Something about how it creates the web host in test it doesn't like.. I added the client to the CORS statement which is http://localhost but still doesn't like DELETE or PUT verbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    HttpResponseMessage responseDelete = await Client.GetAsync("/api/RfAttachment/DeleteById/1");
    responseDelete.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

This is wrong, you are calling `GetAsync`, you are supposed to call `DeleteAsync` as you have marked your method with `[HttpDelete]` verb.

```
    HttpResponseMessage responseDelete = await Client.DeleteAsync("/api/RfAttachment/DeleteById/1");
    responseDelete.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your IWebHost is running under IIS / IISExpress, you may need to enable PUT and DELETE on IIS.

The following items must be set to enable:

- Website Application Pool Managed Pipeline Mode must be set to ***Integrated***
- HTTP Verbs must be supported in IIS

Set Application Pool Pipeline Mode

- Go to IIS Manager > Application Pools
- Locate Application Pool for target:

  - (website) > Edit (double-click) > Managed pipeline mode: Integrated

HTTP Verb Update

The following snippet should be added to `web.config` to enable all verbs, and to ensure that `WebDAV` does not intercept and reject `PUT` and `DELETE`. If the default `WebDAV` is configured, `WebDAV` will intercept `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs, returning 405 errors (method not allowed).

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.AspNet" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

If you prefer a [GUI to add verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440277/how-do-i-enable-http-put-and-delete-for-asp-net-mvc-in-iis), go to IIS Manager > Handler Mappings. Find `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0`, double click it. Click `Request Restrictions...` button and on `Verbs` tab, add both `DELETE` and `PUT`.

[image: IIS Verbs]

Answer (score 0):

See more details in this post
[.netcore PUT method 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017003/netcore-put-method-405-method-not-allowed/70511879#70511879)

Include this line in the Web.Config file

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
             <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```