# Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'. when converting Delegates

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, delegates

I am trying to convert from a generic delegate to a named delegate.

With the result being in spirit of the following (not valid C#):

```
Action<CustomClass> act = ???;
CustomDelegate d = act;
```

I have tried

```
CustomDelegate d = act.Invoke;
CustomDelegate d = new CustomDelegate( act );
CustomDelegate d = new CustomDelegate( x => act(x) );
CustomDelegate d = new CustomDelegate( act.Invoke );
```

All of which fail at run time giving an `ArgumentException` with the  error

> Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.

The top of the stack which is not my code is:

> at System.MulticastDelegate.ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance()
>
> at System.MulticastDelegate.CtorClosed(object target, IntPtr methodPtr)

How to I convert a delegate such that I do not get an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ultimately found the answer by trying [@DiegoMijelshon's solution for a question on casting delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1906829/1072626).  With that solution I got a `NullReferenceException` instead of the `ArgumentException`.  Thus I found the issue was because the Action<> I had was null (it was a parameter). Thus, a null check such as the following fixed my issue.

```
CustomDelegate d = adt == null ? null : act.Invoke;
// Though, I actually went with @DiegoMijelshon solution to avoid extra indirection.
```

I then went and looked with reflector (which I should have done sooner) and found that it is indeed a null check on the parameter that causes `ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance` to be called.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exception in a different context.

Consider the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Demo.CallAction1(null); //instance is null!
    }
    
    public class Demo
    {
        public void DemoAction1() {}
        public void DemoAction2() {}
        
        public static void Execute(Action a) { a();}
        
        public static void CallAction1(Demo d)  { Execute(d.DemoAction1); }
    }
}
```

You will get this error:

```
Run-time exception (line 18): Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.

Stack Trace:

[System.ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.]
   at System.MulticastDelegate.CtorClosed(Object target, IntPtr methodPtr)
   at Program.Demo.CallAction1(Demo d) :line 18
   at Program.Main() :line 8
```

See:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/lELV2s