# Convert Func to Delegate

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic, delegates

I have the following delegate defined:

```
public delegate object MyDelegate(dynamic target);
```

And I have a `Func<dynamic, object>` object:

```
Func<dynamic, object> myFunc
```

How can I convert `myFunc` to `MyDelegate`?

I have tried these instructions, none of them worked:

```
MyDelegate myDeleg = myFunc;
MyDelegate myDeleg = (MyDelegate) myFunc;
MyDelegate myDeleg = myFunc as MyDelegate;
```

Comment: I think the nicest one is `MyDelegate myDeleg = myFunc.Invoke;`, from [Cast delegate to Func in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1907135/7586). There is also `MyDelegate myDeleg = new MyDelegate(myFunc)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can wrap the existing delegate:

```
(MyDelegate)(x => myFunc(x))
```

Or equivalently:

```
MyDelegate myDeleg = x => myFunc(x);
```

This causes a small performance loss on each invocation but the code is very simple.

Comment: Just to be explicit, that's `MyDelegate myDeleg = x => myFunc(x);` - without casting.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not just `new MyDelegate(myFunc)`?

Comment: @tymtam does that work to convert between delegate types? I have never seen that.

Comment: Yes, it should. Let's have 
`class A {
        public A(D d) { d.Invoke("I'm A!"); }
        public delegate object D(dynamic target);
    }` and `class B{
        public delegate object D(dynamic target);
    }` 
and `object F(dynamic s) { Console.WriteLine(s); return null; }` and `Func<dynamic, object> f = F;`. Then you can `new A(new A.D(new B.D(f)));`

Comment: @tymtam indeed. You should post an answer.

Comment: @usr I would add an anwser, but this Q is a duplicate and I cannot :)

Comment: @tymtam: If you merged one relevant line from your comment into your answer on the duplicate question, I would be pretty sure that you'd get many upvotes. But this long example there is nothing that a typical reader wants to see. TLDR. Keep the example, but add one main line at the very top.